# Compiling Qt 5.3.0 for static linking under windows

Tags: qt, static, compilation

I am trying to compile Qt for static linking following this tutorial: http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW

But i receive tons of warnings and a few errors.

For example this one:

```
C:/Developement/Qt/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqjp2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:79: recipe for target '..\..\bin\dumpdoc.exe' failed
mingw32-make[4]: *** [..\..\bin\dumpdoc.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: Target 'first' not remade because of errors.
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'C:/Developement/Qt/Static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0/qtactiveqt/tools/dumpdoc'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: Target 'first' not remade because of errors.
```

for this, i set the environement variable to my path:

```
Name: LIBRARY_PATH
Value: C:\Developement\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin
```

... but dunno yet if its gonna workin'

Beside this, i put the following paths to the PATH environement variable:

```
C:\Developement\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin;
C:\Developement\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\bin;
```

I am receiving tons of these kind of warning:

> In file included from
>   C:\Developement\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0\qtbase\src\3rdparty\libjpeg/jpeglib.h:25:0,
>                    from ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_jpeglib.h:74,
>                    from ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:75:
>   C:\Developement\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0\qtbase\src\3rdparty\libjpeg/jconfig.h:55:0:
>   warning:  "HAVE_STDDEF_H" redefined [enabled by default]  #define
>   HAVE_STDDEF_H  ^ In file included from
>   ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\include/jasper/jas_tvp.h:75:0,
>                    from ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:70:
>   ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\include/jasper/jas_config.h:65:0:
>   note: this is the location of the previous definition  #define
>   HAVE_STDDEF_H 1  ^ In file included from
>   C:\Developement\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0\qtbase\src\3rdparty\libjpeg/jpeglib.h:25:0,
>                    from ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_jpeglib.h:74,
>                    from ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:75:
>   C:\Developement\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0\qtbase\src\3rdparty\libjpeg/jconfig.h:59:0:
>   warning:  "HAVE_STDLIB_H" redefined [enabled by default]  #define
>   HAVE_STDLIB_H  ^
>       In file included from ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\include/jasper/jas_tvp.h:75:0,
>                    from ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:70:
>       ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\include/jasper/jas_config.h:71:0:
>   note: this is the location of the previous definition
>       #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
>       ^
>       ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c: In function 'jpg_decode':
>       ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:134:49: warning: parameter 'optstr' set but not used 
>       [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
>       jas_image_t *jpg_decode(jas_stream_t *in, char *optstr)
>                                                    ^
>       ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c: In function 'jpg_start_output':
>       ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:298:47: warning: parameter 'cinfo' set but not used
>   [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
>       static void jpg_start_output(j_decompress_ptr cinfo, jpg_dest_t *dinfo)
>                                                  ^
>       ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c: In function 'jpg_finish_output':
>       ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:335:48: warning: parameter 'cinfo' set but not used
>   [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
>       static void jpg_finish_output(j_decompress_ptr cinfo, jpg_dest_t *dinfo)
>                                                   ^    ......\3rdparty\jasper\src\libjasper\jpg\jpg_dec.c:335:67: warning:
>   parameter 'dinfo' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
>       static void jpg_finish_output(j_decompress_ptr cinfo, jpg_dest_t *dinfo)
>                                                                      ^

Wasn't i prepared enough to compile Qt?

What do i need to do in order to be able to compile Qt without getting errors everytime thrown out?

How long would it take until its compiled.

Comment: my solution for my "simple" project was:  Nana: https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana